# Escaping variables in java

Tags: java, escaping

Can you escape variables in Java? For example, in PHP, I can do this:

```
$test = 3;
echo "He is {$test} years old";
```

Which will output:

```
 He is 3 years old
```

Can you do a similar thing in Java?

Comment: In a word - no. In more words, yes, if they're not local variables, but it is very complicated, and you really shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: @George Newton In PHP you don't need to surround the variable on brackets if you are enclosing the string with double quotes, it will evaluate the variable. Just use quotes for accessing object members like {$test->getName()}. In this case echo "He is $test years old"; will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use String.format

```
int age = 3;
String newString = String.format("He is %d years old", age);
```

%d - says int.
%s - is for string, %f for float, and more and more formatting options.

You can find a very good explenation [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html):

Noam.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this way

```
Int x=3;
String test="He is "+x+"years old";
System.out.println(test);
output
He is 3 years old
```

Comment: I know you can do that. I was just curious whether you could escape the variable in such a way that didn't require concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but I would do

```
 int age = 3;

System.out.println("He is " + age + " years old");
```